# Using partial view, and second controller on one view in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a question: how can 1 view/page use 2 controllers to display different data?

For example:

1) Page displays DVD's information using DvdController.

2) On that same page I want to use a Template/Partial view, that displays list of actors, and that list should come from the second ActorsController.

I can add a template view inside another page but the second controller doesn't work:

MainPage on URL: `website/dvd`

```
{% block body %}
    <div>
        <h1>{{ dvd.title }} </h1>
    </div>

    <div>
            {{ include('DVDBundle:Actors:actors.html.twig') }}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Above I use the partial view `actors.html.twig` to show the actors, strangely the html code/div's and so on are actually displayed and working on the page, however the controllers(ActorsController) method that meant to return this partial view is not executed for some reason.?

But if I go to the view directly via link: `website/actors` then its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symfony documentation on [embedded controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) explains this nicely.

In short, you will need to do something like this in your template file:

```
<div>
    {{ render(controller(
        'DVDBundle:Actors:actors',
        { ... parameters to the controller action here ... }
    )) }}
</div>
```

The important thing is calling the `render` function, which allows a controller to be rendered, as opposed to simply `include`ing a template. (This assumes that your have an ActorsController with an actorsAction method; change the names as appropriate to your controller.)

Comment: Thank You - Another thing to clarify: if the partial view contains a form, the   Request returns an error, something related to fragment and for bitten permissions. going directly to the form url works but via partial view it doesnt. I also found this comment: but its not clear what to do?: "When using a controller instead of a URL, you must enable the Symfony fragments configuration:"

Comment: Maybe use this link now https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/embedding_controllers.html (Symfony 3.4)